# How can I restore a .lms file created on Mindstorms Inventor to another device?

Tags: mindstorms, robot-inventor

I have Mindstorms Inventor. I have been able to send my `.lms` files to my computer as backup. Now I would like to be able to load those programs on another device. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On desktop, click *File* > *Open...*. or double-click on the file in a file browser.

[image: screenshot of menu]

On Android, you will need a file browsing app like *Files*. Find the file and tap on it. You may be asked which app to use. Pick *MINDSTORMS*.

[image: screenshot of android]

Comment: David.   Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Glad to help. You can help others find this information too by selecting this as the correct answer.